# How to make scatter plots with semitransparent points in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, transparent, point, scatter

How can I plot an image with partially transparent scatter points, just like in the picture below, with Gnuplot? The problem is that I don’t know how to set the points to be transparent.

[image: A scatter plot example]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very useful. But sorry I don't know how to mark your answer as correct. By the way, I found another way to do this is to make statistics to get the density of each point first then plot with palette in gnuplot. Thank you again!

Comment: Forget `gnuplot`, how was that plot above made? Seems like an even better form of `smoothScatter`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
set style fill  transparent solid 0.35 noborder
set style circle radius 0.02
plot 'test' u 1:2 with circles lc rgb "blue", \
     '' u 1:2 every 100 w circles lc rgb "red" fs solid 1.0 border lt -1
```

which outputs
[image]

As you can see, you can specify for each data set whether to use transparency and which color to use.
If your data consist of two values (x and y position of the circle) you have to specify the circle's radius via `set style circle ...`. If your data has three rows, you can use the third value to specify the circle's radius for each data point.
You can play with the transparency level, which ranges from 0 (full transparency) to 1 (no transparency).

Answer (score 14):

You can use the alpha channel of argb along with `lc rgb variable`:

```
set samp 2000
randn(x) = invnorm(rand(x))
pl [-3:3][-3:3] '+' us (randn(0)):(randn(0)):(0xBB00AAFF) lc rgb variable pt 7 ps 2
```

[image: lp 7].

This leaves some egde around each circle, probably an opacity effect from a circle plus a filled circle on top of it. Unfortunately, there is no edgecolor option as in matplotlib to control this. Replacing filled circles `pt 7` with open circles but thick linewidth `pt 6 lw 6` can mitigate this a bit

```
pl [-3:3][-3:3] '+' us (randn(0)):(randn(0)):(0xBB00AAFF) lc rgb variable pt 6 lw 6
```

[image: pt 6 lw 6].

One can also emulate a **variable transparency** with `lc rgb variable`

```
set samp 50
pl '+' us 1:1:(0x00AAFF+(int(0xFF*$1/10.)<<24)) pt 7 lc rgb variable ps 3
```

where `int(0xFF*$1/10.)` maps the input from 0..10 into 0..255 and `<<24` shifts it into the alpha channel.

[image]

Note that in your plot only the dense regions seem to have a transparency effect, but not the scatter points in the background.