# How to plot (x,y,z) points showing their density

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, density-plot

My data file is a set of (x,y,z) points located around the axis origin. They represent points where a kind of measure has failed.
These points are in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1aesne7r7mybny/data.dat?dl=0).

Gnuplot can plot them,

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set term postscript eps enhanced color size 4.7in,4in
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set zlabel "Z"
set output "test_gp.eps"
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7 ps 0.5 lt 1 lw 0.5 # --- blue
set style fill  transparent solid 0.15 noborder
splot "data.dat" u 1:2:3 w p ls 1 title "P_{error}"
```

with the resulting plot

[image]

The problem is that the figure does not show where the error is more likely to occur. 
I would like to show the variations in the density of points if it is possible.

I do not know if it is possible to vary the color of the points or give them transparency and try to represent the locations with the most density of points.

If a representation of the density of 3D points is not possible, another way could be to make a projection density of the points in the three planes (x=0,y,z), (x,y=0,z), (x,y,z=0).

Regards

**EDIT:**

I can plot with different colors the success (`0`) and error (`1`) point locations of my experiment. The file in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cww9q0onrgn788o/data_all.dat?dl=0) has a 4th column with all data samples ( 0's and 1's).

The `splot` figure

```
splot "data_all.dat" u 1:2:3:4 w points ls 1 palette title "P_{error}"
```

is

[image]

but this figure is not showing the density of points.
For example, in Mathematica the density plot of these data samples is

[image]

How could I get the density plot with `Gnuplot`?. It is likely that Mathematica is doing an interpolation of the points in the middle and give them values between 0 and 1, but I do not know how to achieve it with Gnuplot.

Comment: with your code your datapoints are not transparent. Instead set linecolor for example to `rgb '#cc0060ad'`, according to the scheme `#aarrggbb`. `aa` will be the alpha channel. About calculating the density, I don't know how Mathematica does it or how it could be done in gnuplot but basically it is counting the points in a certain small volume and assigning a color to it. This reminds me to `smooth frequency` and binning, but in 3D.

Comment: @theozh I believe this is not possible in Gnuplot.
I can make a 2D  density plot making a matrix. Each position of the matrix is a xy bin (a 2D bin), and the value is the count of xy numbers that fall in that 2D bin. In link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159983/count-number-of-points-in-2d-bins?noredirect=1#comment79374603_46159983
The solution shows how to generate that matrix of numbers from a xy data samples. With the matrix is possible to make the heatmap like in the first example of http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html

Comment: @theozh The problem here is similar but with 3D bins are more difficult to generate, and there is no example of doing 3D heatmaps with Gnuplot.
Therefore, I believe Gnuplot does not implement a way to do it. 

A workaround would be make a heat map for the three coordinates planes (x,y, z=0), (x,y=0, z), (x =0 ,y, z). And represent the three heatmaps together in the XYZ coordinates system (like projections). I can generate the three heat maps (although I did not try it yet I believe is possible), but I do not know how to join the three of them in the coordinates system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@user1993416, I guess you can do something with gnuplot. You might want to play with the parameter `Radius` for determining the number of points around a certain point within this radius and calculating the density. With my 8 year old computer 1000 points need approx. 2-3 minutes.

***Update:** After revisiting this old post, I noticed that there was a unnecessary loop in test data creation and the script can be made much faster by using only arrays, i.e. no writing to tables which seems to be much slower than arrays. Now, it takes about approx. 2, 7 and 26 seconds for 500, 1000 and 2000 points. So, runtime is `O(n^2)`.*

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### 3D density plot
reset session
set term wxt
TimeStart = time(0.0)

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 1000
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))) with table
unset table

# put the datafile/dataset into arrays
stats $Data u 0 nooutput
N = STATS_records
array X[N]
array Y[N]
array Z[N]
array C[N]
stats $Data u (X[$0+1]=$1, Y[$0+1]=$2, Z[$0+1]=$3) nooutput

# look at each datapoint and its sourrounding
Radius = 2
V      = pi*4/3*Radius**3   # sphere volume
p0     = 0;  dp = 10        # progress steps
do for [i=1:N] {
    if (p=real(i)/N*100, p>=p0 ? p0=(floor(p/dp)+1)*dp : 0) {
        print sprintf("Progress: %.0f%%", p)
    } 
    C[i] = 0
    stats $Data u ( C[i] = C[i] + \
          (sqrt((X[i]-$1)**2 + (Y[i]-$2)**2 + (Z[i]-$3)**2) <= Radius )) nooutput
}
print sprintf("Time elapsed: %.3f sec",time(0.0)-TimeStart)

set key noautotitle
set xyplane relative 0
set view equal xyz
set view 65,45,1.2
set palette rgb 33,13,10

splot X u (X[$0+1]):(Y[$0+1]):(Z[$0+1]):(C[$0+1]/V) w p ps 1 pt 7 lc palette z

set terminal gif animate delay 20
set output "SO53659762.gif"
    a0     = 40
    a1     = 60
    Frames = 24
    do for [i=0:Frames] {
        set view 65,(sin(2*pi*i/(Frames+1))*(a1-a0)+a0)
        replot
    }
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (output to gif terminal)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have to test your solution with my samples. I have some XYZ points that are an error ('1') and other data successful ('0'). I figure out that I should test with just one class of data (e.g., errors) and see if the output provides information about where errors are prone to occur. However, I think that considering one type of data will not give me all the info. I will try it.

Comment: My Gnuplot 5.2 does not have the `wxt` terminal. Which terminal should I try?. I would like to test the gif, but finally, I want to use just one of the views for my report.

Comment: Besides, Is it possible to add a heat map of the points in the XY plane to the 3D representation?

Comment: instead of wxt you should be able to use your standard terminal. I inserted this just because the first `splot...` I did to my standard and the animation to the `gif` terminal. I am confident that two data classes can be handled and also the heatmap on the XY plane... needs some more coding.

Comment: The new added codding I would like to make is different to what I was asking here. Therefore, I will open a new question asking the coding extensions. If allowed I would like to invite you to take a look. Thank you.